# JavaScript window.print() not working

Tags: javascript

Here is the simple page with a table. I want to print it on button click. But the script is not working.

```
<html><head><style>th{background-color:#000}table, th, td {  border: 1px solid black; }    </style></head><body><center>
<TABLE id=highlight class=hilite border=1 cellSpacing=5 cellPadding=4><THEAD    style="COLOR: white">
<TR>
<TH colSpan=2>MINI STATEMENT</TH></TR></THEAD>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=row width="15%"><B>Account Id</B></TD>
<TD class=row><B>A000000003</B></TD></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=row width="15%">Your Previous Balance</TD>
<TD class=row width="15%">2539.62</TD></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=row width="15%">Your Current Balance</TD>
<TD class=row width="15%">2538.62 </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><input type='button'    onClick='window.print()' value='Print'></center></body></html>
```

This is maintenance code of a dummy project so just ignore standards and conventions :p For practice.

Comment: I am getting it in firefox 19.0, which browser?

Comment: it's working.check in chrome.

Comment: I am doing it in IE8 :(

Comment: I tried out this on IE7/8 and it's working fine for me.

Comment: ohkay dont know whats going wrong in here

Answer (score 2):

Try like this...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function openWin() {
      var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
      myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");

      myWindow.document.close();
      myWindow.focus();
      myWindow.print();
      myWindow.close();

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution: Adblock chrome extension seems be related if print frame appears only after others events like print again, refresh, etc. Remove the extension and try again.