# go to previous window automatically after printing dialog closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter-3

I have a page where the html elements reside and print function is called via javascript at the end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.print();
    window.history.back();
})
</script>
```

now I have this code to redirect user after print or if cancel is clicked. it works on local but in live server it goes to the previous page immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to go back to previous page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.print();
   history.go(-1); 
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.print();
   history.back(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try with [`window.onafterprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint) function.

> *The afterprint event is raised after the user prints or aborts a print
>   dialog.*

Unfortunately, [only works in FF & IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint#Browser_compatibility)

So for your code (and only for FF & IE), I will try with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.print();
    })
    window.onafterprint = function() {
        history.go(-1);
    };
</script>
```

Now, **for *Webkit-based browser* use matchMedia('print')**...
Something like...

```
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        console.log('onbeforeprint equivalent');
    } else {
        console.log('onafterprint equivalent');
    }
});
```

Source:
[WindowEventHandlers.onafterprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint)
[Detecting Print Requests with JavaScript](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/)
[onbeforeprint and onafterprint is not working in Chrome and IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598790/onbeforeprint-and-onafterprint-is-not-working-in-chrome-and-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try print in a new window?

Something like this:

```
    var myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print();
    myWindow.close();
    myWindow.history.back();
```

Reference: [JavaScript window.print() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127370/javascript-window-print-not-working)

Comment: thank you for quick reply but print function works fine, what I need is when print or cancel button is clicked it should redirect the page to previous one.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    window.print();
    setTimeout(() => {
        history.back(); 
    }, 500);
})();
```

This Will Work In All Browser
This Will Get Back IN Previous Page When You Close Your Window
window.print() This Will Execute Till Window Is Closed And After It Execute
This Will Work Fine In All   Browser